# Wrong subnet configuration works anyway in a shared bus, but doesn't work in switched lan. Why?

Tags: ipv4, subnet, networking, switching, lan

I was told that this configuration (which contains an error in DNS mask which is /23 instead of /24) works only because it's a SHARED bus. If it was a SWITCHED lan, the DNS responses from DNS to A wouldn't "be forwarded". Why?

[image]

Basically A, in order to communicate with DNS, has to pass THROUGH the DG (default gateway) because A sees the DNS address in another subnet. On the other hand, the DNS sees A in his same subnet (since IP A is inside DNS /23) so DNS "talks" directly (dest macaddress is A instead of DG so it's a direct communication) with A WITHOUT passing through DG.

I was told that this only works because the lan is a shared bus. If it was a switched lan the DNS response wouldn't be forwarded(????) Why? What does it mean? What's the issue?

Comment: On the other side: https://superuser.com/questions/1812671/wrong-subnet-configuration-works-anyway-in-a-shared-bus-but-doesnt-work-in-swi/

Comment: Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Obsolete shared-medium or repeated Ethernet with hubs or switched doesn't matter.

Both /24 subnets run in the same L2 segment, and there's a gateway routing in between. /24 hosts use the gateway to reach the other /24 network. /23 hosts talk to them directly. Both methods work, even asymmetrically.

This setup is only useful for educational purposes or perhaps during an address migration, as using a gateway when you don’t really have to is inefficient.